# Firebase CLI: the following filters were specified but do not match any functions in the project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I use `Firebase Cloud Functions` in my project, and I have a plenty of them so when I run the regular `firebase deploy` I exceed the quota, so one option is to deploy only the function that was modified by using `firebase deploy --only functions:function1` as mentioned in [this web page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#deploy_specific_functions). This method works only with functions that start with: `exports.funcName` but when I try to use it with a function like this:

```
function doesNotStartWithExports() {
    // Does something.
}
```

It doesn't work. I use `firebase deploy --only functions:doesNotStartWithExports` but I get this output:

```
⚠  functions: the following filters were specified but do not match any functions in the project: doesNotStartWithExports
```

**The Question: How to deploy Firebase functions that does not start with exports?**

Answer (score 6):

I faced a very similar error while trying to delete some deprecated functions:

`firebase functions:delete mymodule-helloWorld --region us-central1`

Output:

`Error: The specified filters do not match any existing functions in project my-firebase-project.`

Turns out that if I replace the '-' in namespaced/grouped (module) functions with '.', the error goes away. Weird.

`firebase functions:delete mymodule.helloWorld --region us-central1`

Output:

```
? You are about to delete the following Cloud Functions:
    mymodule-helloWorld(us-central1)
  Are you sure? Yes
i  functions: deleting function mymodule-helloWorld(us-central1)...
✔  functions[mymodule-helloWorld(us-central1)]: Successful delete operation.
```

The solution is adapted from this [github thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/672#issuecomment-659478126)

Comment: awesome, to delete multiple functions, use `firebase functions:delete mod-function1 mod-function2 mod-function3` i.e. use a space between function names

Answer (score 4):

I actually found the solution, and it's by deploying one of the function that starts with `exports` and uses the function that doesn't start with `exports`, for example:

```
function doesNotStartWithExports() {
    // I want to deploy only this function but I can't
}

exports.anotherFunction = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    // This functions uses the one that I want to deploy.
    doesNotStartWithExports()
})
```

To update `doesNotStartWithExports` I use this command:
`firebase deploy --only functions:anotherFunction`.

Answer (score 2):

I also found that if you have a regular function exported somewhere with the same name as the Firestore function you will get this error:

```
export myFunction() {
  // do somethig here
} 

exports.myFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // function
})
```

renaming either of them to a unique name will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This works:
[image]

But this does not work (extra lines preceding function)
[image]